# dependencies error when pushing discord.js bot to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js

https://github.com/Jytesh/Krunker_Design_Hub_Bot
Can't push my app to heroku I am getting an error --> `Cannot find module 'internal/util/types'`

I tried Deleting and re installing package.json and then re-installing my node_modules file.

`remote:        - A module may be missing from 'dependencies' in package.json`
error is recieved